# Parallel.Foreach loop never ends

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

My code executes as I would expect on smaller loops, but when I iterate through larger IP Ranges the process seems to stop short and never complete.

The program keeps running, and no exceptions are thrown.

```
public void Discover()
{
    Int32 MaxThreadCount     = 20, 
        DevicesProcessed     = 0;
    List<String> IPAddresses = GetIPAddresses(IPRangesToCheck).ToList();

    using (cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
    {

        ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions();
        po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxThreadCount;
        po.CancellationToken = cts.Token;

        try
        {
            var deviceInfo = new DeviceInfo();

            Parallel.ForEach(IPAddresses, po, (item, loopState) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("DevicesProcessed: {0}, IPAddresses.Count: {1}", DevicesProcessed, IPAddresses.Count.ToString());
                    if (DevicesProcessed >= IPAddresses.Count)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("!!!THRESHOLD REACHED!!!");
                        cts.Cancel();
                    }

                    if (loopState.ShouldExitCurrentIteration || loopState.IsExceptional)
                    {
                        loopState.Stop();
                        DiscoverStatus = Devices.DiscoverState.Stopped;
                    }

                    var response = CheckIPAndReturnInfo(item);

                    if (loopState.ShouldExitCurrentIteration || loopState.IsExceptional)
                    {
                        loopState.Stop();
                        DiscoverStatus = Devices.DiscoverState.Stopped;
                    }

                    if (response != null)
                    {
                        FoundDevices.Add(response);
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "Device Count {0}, IP Address {1}",
                            DevicesProcessed,
                            item);
                    }

                    Interlocked.Increment(ref DevicesProcessed);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.Write("Error! = " + ex.Message);

                    if (deviceInfo.State == CommunicationState.Faulted)
                    {
                        loopState.Stop();
                    }
                }
            });

            RaiseAllItemsCompleteEvent();

        }
        catch (AggregateException aggEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Parrallel Exception!: " + aggEx);
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the range 172.16.0.0 to 172.16.255.255 there are 65536 IP Addresses to check. The program gets to 65519 before ceasing to process any more addresses and not progressing further in the code.
At this point no breakpoints are hit anywhere in the code.

The `if (DevicesProcessed >= IPAddresses.Count)` section was an attempt to manually cancel the loop once it was finished, but unfortunately it doesn't get that far. Canceling, before this point does work correctly.

I have been unable to find anyone else experiencing this sort of issue with Parallel tasks and I am quite stumped. Any advice on ways to further debug the issue would be appreciated.

I have added a stopwatch to my `CheckIPAndReturnInfo` class, to see how long it takes to elapse. This is where the `Start:` and `End:` output text is generated. Here is a sample of the output, where the program falls over:

```
DevicesProcessed: 65515, IPAddresses.Count: 65536
Start : 172.16.114.94
End : 172.16.114.94 Elaspsed: 00:00:01.4247110
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.TimeoutException' occurred in SharpSnmpLib.dll
End : 172.16.114.60 Elaspsed: 00:00:07.0803977
DevicesProcessed: 65517, IPAddresses.Count: 65536
Start : 172.16.114.61
A first chance exception of type 'Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.TimeoutException' occurred in SharpSnmpLib.dll
End : 172.16.114.76 Elaspsed: 00:00:07.0807436
DevicesProcessed: 65518, IPAddresses.Count: 65536
Start : 172.16.114.77
A first chance exception of type 'Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.TimeoutException' occurred in SharpSnmpLib.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1664) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.TimeoutException' occurred in SharpSnmpLib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.TimeoutException' occurred in SharpSnmpLib.dll
End : 172.16.114.61 Elaspsed: 00:00:07.0806001
DevicesProcessed: 65519, IPAddresses.Count: 65536
Start : 172.16.114.62
A first chance exception of type 'Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.TimeoutException' occurred in SharpSnmpLib.dll
End : 172.16.114.77 Elaspsed: 00:00:07.0807928
DevicesProcessed: 65520, IPAddresses.Count: 65536
Start : 172.16.114.78
A first chance exception of type 'Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.TimeoutException' occurred in SharpSnmpLib.dll
The thread '<No Name>' (0xf90) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b24) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.TimeoutException' occurred in SharpSnmpLib.dll
A first chance exception of type 'Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.TimeoutException' occurred in SharpSnmpLib.dll
End : 172.16.114.62 Elaspsed: 00:00:07.0806679
A first chance exception of type 'Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Messaging.TimeoutException' occurred in SharpSnmpLib.dll
End : 172.16.114.78 Elaspsed: 00:00:07.0804395
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1518) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1e1c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1190) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1218) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1c68) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1b20) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0xa14) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x185c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x430) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Can you set a conditional breakpoint and then step through at the point just before failure?

Comment: you call cts.Cancel() already so why not do this check as well if(cts.IsCancellationRequested) return;

Comment: `CancellationTokenSource` implements `IDisposable` and therefore should be disposed after you're done with it. Easiest way is to wrap its use in a `using` statement.

Comment: @CodeBlend I've done that step and the loop executes fine, it just doesn't progress past that, or exit the loop. It's strange behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

1. Do not use `IsCompleted` in your if statement. Just put `RaiseAllItemsCompleteEvent` after `Parallel.ForEach`.
2. In your exception handler, don't re-throw the exception, as it will cause `Parallel` to error out. Just use `loopState.Stop`.

Silly example:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(0, 100),
    (i, state) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        if(i==11) state.Stop();
    });
RaiseAllItemsCompleteEvent();
```

And in your conditional checks, just use `if(loopState.IsStopped)`. Given your `try/catch` block, it would be difficult to hit `IsExceptional`.

Finally, because you are running in Parallel, you must use `Interlocked.Increment(ref DevicesProcessed)`. Otherwise, the count will not be accurate.

Comment: This is good advice, thank you for that. I have changed my code to using `Interlocked.Increment` (which I did know about, and kicked myself for forgetting) but I the loops is still stopping short (16 from the amount of processed device) and no exiting the `parallel.foreach`

Comment: Can you post the output it generates?

Comment: Is FoundDevices thread safe? Could you add some output after Parallel but before Raise, to find out if you still are in the loop? Is there a timeout in the CheckIpAndReturnInfo?

Comment: FoundDevices is a ConcurrentBag, so will be threadsafe. I'm going to look into your other points and generate some new output.

Answer (score 0):

`cts.Cancel()` can throw `AggregateException`

Catch it inner try as well and see if its hits there, if that is happening in your current code absence of  inner `AggregateException' it will go infinite loop.

Comment: I am catching `Exception` so this would cover `AggregateException` also.